# Cannot alert contents of firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck on a stupid problem. I want to display the contents of the Firebase database in a readable form but I cannot do it properly as it only recognizes its an object.

```
findData(){
  firebase.database().ref('/').on('child_added',(snapshot)=>{
    alert(snapshot.val())
  })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** to display in alert,

```
  alert(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))
```

Comment: Mark if that helped

Comment: I will do. I have two fields in the array 'firstName' and 'secondName'. How would I extract them?

Comment: you need to use (JSON.parse(snapshot.val()).whateverProperty)

Comment: when I use 'alert(JSON.parse(snapshot.val()).name)' I get the error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: what do you see when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())).

Comment: I see this : {"belt":"Heavyweight","name":"Mcgregor"}

Comment: console.log((JSON.parse(snapshot.val()).name); ?

Comment: I get this error: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)